# ms access data type mismatch in criteria expression when passing a variable into a sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am getting a data type mismatch with the following code.  However, it looks fine when I do a debug print.

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date

StartDate = “1/1/2019”
EndDate = “2/1/2019”


strSQL = SELECT Table1.Start INTO 1 FROM Table1 WHERE (((Table1.Start) BETWEEN ‘“ & StartDate & “‘“ & “ AND ‘“ & EndDate & “‘));”
```

Debug.Print strSQL

```
Docmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

Comment: Please post actual code that actually compiles, by copying it from your code window.

Comment: Table1.start is a Date/Time field.  It works if I use:  strSQL = SELECT Table1.Start INTO 1 FROM Table1 WHERE (((Table1.Start) BETWEEN #1/1/2019# And #2/1/2019#));”

Answer (score 1):

Use the correct syntax for dates and date value expressions:

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date

StartDate = #1/1/2019#
EndDate = #2/1/2019#


strSQL = "SELECT Table1.Start INTO 1 FROM Table1 WHERE (((Table1.Start) BETWEEN #" & Format(StartDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# AND #" & Format(EndDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#);"
```